# Calculate incident matrix multiplied by its trasnpose by using adjacency matrix and degree matrix.

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

A few days ago I saw this question in Graph theory and couldn't find any solution for it.
Consider X as an incident matrix,
A as an adjacency matrix,
and D as an degree matrix.
then find the answer of X.X^t according to A and D.

Comment: What approaches have you tried? Did you calculate $XX^T$ for some simple graph to get some intuitions?

Comment: @dtldarek , yeah i guess it's A+D.